# Python special character unicode

Tags: python, variables, unicode

I have a python script in which one I specify an argument :

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-D", "--departure", dest="departure",default="", type="string",help="specify departure")
```

and in my script i have to to a few things with the string entered.

When I type : -D "Düsseldorf"

the string is not recognized properly in the script

somebody told me to do u"Düsseldorf" but I need to stock "Düsseldorf" in a variable

something like variable = u+"Düsseldorf" .... hmm I really don;t know how to do that.

Thank you for your help.

Regards.

Comment: That somebody also sent you a link to ["Unicode In Python, Completely Demystified"](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).  Maybe you should read it. :)

Answer (score 0):

[PEP-0264](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) explains you how to use Unicode in python scripts.

Or, for lazy ones, start your script with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print u"Düsseldorf"
```

And do not forget to solve it as UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you need to specify a character encoding for your Python source that can represent the `ü` character:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But you also need to keep in mind that command line arguments (in Unix at least, I can't speak for Windows) are bytes.  So you should specify the option as a byte-string not a character (Unicode) string.

For example:

```
parser.add_option("-D", "--departure", dest="departure",
default=u"Düsseldorf".encode('UTF-8'),
type="string",help="specify departure")
```

Now the default argument is a byte-string, just like all the other arguments you have passed to the `add_option` method.

Additionally you must ensure that if someone enters this string into their terminal, they do so with a terminal character encoding of UTF-8.  If they use a different terminal character encoding, a different byte-string will show up in the command line.  This is simply how Unix works, and Python has no power to change it.

Comment: So how can I do : myvar = "Düsseldorf"  then myvar2 = umyvar ?

Comment: In Python 2 the statement `myvar = "Düsseldorf"` is not really valid, because without using the `u` prefix you are specifying a byte-string, and ASCII is used implicitly to interpret literal byte-strings.

Comment: In Python 2, `'strings like this'` are byte-strings and `u'strings like this'` are character-strings.  In Python 3 `'strings like this'` are character-strings and `b'strings like this'` are byte-strings.  In both cases the byte-strings are implicitly interpreted using ASCII, so a character like `ü` should not appear in a byte-string literal.

Comment: This article is perhaps a bit condescending but nonetheless an invaluable piece of knowledge.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html